# Differences between Next.js and React app using styled components

Tags: next.js, styled-components

I am migrating my app from SPA React to Next.js

I have found this weird bug wherein the SPA I have `max-width: 100%` while in Next.js `width: fit-content`

I cannot understand where the different behavior is coming from, I know I can fix it easily but I would like to understand the causes.

code is

```
const RadioButtonWrapper = styled.div`
  color: ${({ theme, dark }) => theme.global.colors[dark ? 'white' : 'black']};
  svg {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    fill: ${({ theme, dark }) => theme.global.colors[dark ? 'white' : 'black']};
  }
  [class^="StyledRadioButton__StyledRadioButtonContainer"] {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
  }
  [class^="StyledBox__StyledBoxGap"] {
    height: 0;
  }
  [class^="StyledRadioButton__StyledRadioButtonBox"] {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: ${({ theme, dark }) => theme.global.colors[dark ? 'white' : 'black']};
    margin-bottom: 1px;
  }
  &:hover {
    [class^="StyledRadioButton__StyledRadioButtonBox"] {
      border-color: ${({ theme, dark }) => theme.global.colors[dark ? 'white' : 'black']} !important;
    }
  }
  label {
    [class^="StyledRadioButton"] {
      flex-shrink: 0;
    }
  }

  ${({ rightAlign }) => rightAlign
    && `  label {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }`}
`;

const RadioButtonGroup = ({ dark, rightAlign, ...props }) => (
  <RadioButtonWrapper dark={dark} rightAlign={rightAlign}>
    <GrommetRadioButtonGroup {...props} />
  </RadioButtonWrapper>
);
```

SPA

[image]

[image]

Next.js

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The difference has to do with what sort of polyfills the two compilers are using to make sure that your code can run in most browsers.

Check out the [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width#browser_compatibility) for the two properties.  max-width has been part of the CSS spec for a very long time and is supported by every browser.  Whereas fit-content is not supported at all in Internet Explorer and needs a prefix for Firefox.

The “max-width: 100%” version is more versatile, so your SPA ships that version.

Next.JS has more advanced polyfill techniques.  They [only ship the backwards compatible version to older browsers which need it](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/10212).  When you run your code in a modern browser you see “width: fit-content”.  If you were to run the code in IE you would see “max-width: 100%” instead.